# Getting an error whenever I try to rerun the gameloop

Tags: python, pygame

```
while gameStart == True:
    startScreen()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            youLose = True
            gameStart = False 
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            moveY = -snek.fast
            moveX = 0
            gameStart = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            youLose = True
            gameStart = False
```

I have no trouble when I run the game the first time around. I'm trying to get the game to reset after I've lost but I keep getting the error:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand why this is giving me an error, and even less why it gives an error only on the second time around. I've tried indenting the block so as to include it inside the `for` loop, but it makes my game crash.

Comment: If the indentation in this question is correct, is issue is you need to intent the KEYDOWN if statement to be inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The keydown if-else statement should be inside the for-loop

```
while gameStart == True:
    startScreen()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            youLose = True
            gameStart = False 
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveY = -snek.fast
                moveX = 0
                gameStart = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                youLose = True
                gameStart = False
```